# Why encode a JSON payload to base64?

Tags: web, base64, payload

On codejam [site](https://codejam.withgoogle.com/2018/challenges/00000000000000cb/scoreboard) they are returning a json string as base64 encoded string.

The actual json payload's size is less than the base64 encoded string.

What's the reason behind returning the payload as base64 encoded string?

Answer (score 0):

7 bit schemes are, or tend to be, transport neutral. There is a natural corruption check as least as good as CRC, and the JSON is less likely to be mangled by well meaning library functions (CRLF, anti-injection, SQL parsing). Yes it's going to be longer. 7 goes into anything more times than 8 (or more).